# How to display multi-day multi-track conference on Joomla with an emphasis on maintainability

Tags: extensions, jevents

I'm part of a committee that run a free conference in the UK across events around the country and we have a joomla site for advertising the event.

Traditionally, each event has had just a single track of speakers and we were able to bumble along with some simple html tables on individual pages.  However, with each event now being multiple tracks and doing a call for speakers our events have become significantly harder to manage and maintain accurate schedules/agenda.

Solutions I'm considering are:

1. A calendar extension - this would enable to addition of lots of unique appointments for each session but would be difficult to maintain due to the vast array of appointments it would create
2. An event extension - this would create specific events, allow me to add maps etc but looking at the two which seemed most popular (ohanah and jevents) did not have demos which included agendas
3. Continuing on with my poor html tables

I'm hoping that some here has experienced a similar problem and found a satisfying solution (ideally in the form of an extension) that they can share

**Examples**

[image: sqlbits agenda]
[image: sqlsaturday agenda]

Comment: JEvents would most likely be my first choice. I would suggest downloading it (it's free) and testing it out on a copy of your site or on a created menu item with special access only. Seems much more flexible to test rather than on their site if they had a demo

Comment: Looking closely at jevent, the agenda functionality is simply creating another article and typing everything up in it so its currently equivalent to my situation

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Event Booking](https://www.joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/events-booking-joomla-events-registration.html) on my personal site. It allows me to setup individual events and to collect registration details/payments for each event I create. You can see a demo on the providers site.

I am also using DPCal Pro on another website which just displays events around the globe. It too is supposed to be able to handle registration, but I don't use it that way as it sits over a publicly accessible google calendar.

Hope one these helps.

Comment: I checked these out but they don't seem to have any features geared towards the management of sessions within each event

Answer (score 1):

I use Ohanah on JoomlaLondon, certain it wouldn't be up to this.  I think I can also help you rule out others I've used, although with overrides one or two of these could possibly be made to suit:

- MiwiEvents, nice because it integrates with MiwiShop(OpenCart highly expandable).
- RSEvents (Needs RSForms for reg and has limited payment gateways). No Agenda View AFAIK but does allow for multiple sessions per event.
- DTRegister is one of the most advanced and flexible events packages but it has it's issues, support being one of them, styling being another. No Agenda View(v2.8.3).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a joomla specific solution, but you might want to look at [sched.org](http://sched.org)

We use it for a large conference with multiple rooms/speakers and it can be embedded into any web page. It's about $200 per event though, so it's quite a bit more than just buying an extension. It does have other benefits, such as adding speaker bios and even exhibitors, and you can even allow people to sign up for their own sched.org account which allows them to flag sessions they like and make their own personal agenda.

Comment: This looked pretty good at first glance, despite the cost, but I noticed that integration with eventbrite would cost  $1 per attendee on top of all the other costs so this be far outside our budget for tech

Comment: Yeah, we didn't interface it with anything. I forgot to mention that. We JUST use it for the schedule. We run out stuff through CiviCRM in our own site (and sometimes DT Register). We hate giving up fees to hosted services where they take a cut of every transaction.